# What exactly does channelReadComplete() do?

Tags: java, netty, nio

I'm wondering how exactly `channelReadComplete()` works. Would it be invoked when channelRead() has completed or when a read operation has completed inside the channelRead() method?

Answer (score 1):

It is invoked when there will be no more reads happening as part to the event loop run and the reads will happen again in the future.

Comment: Right. So basically it will be fired when we receive incoming data from a remote client? In fact we don't even need to override channelRead() because it's irrelevant for invoking channelReadComplete()?

Comment: well in channelReadComplete() you just have a notification when all data was read for the current event loop run while in channelRead(...) you can also intercept the data.